# How to send my score variable to another view controller?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

After I click on a button I go to a new view controller.

I made it possible to make points with `var score = 0` in a IBOutlet and to show to points I use `Score.text = "\(++score)"`.

How can I pass the score to the 'Game over' screen/view controller to a label called "resultScore"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an attribute `secondViewController` in the destination view controller, and use prepareForSegue

`Current View Controller`

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
          if (segue.identifier == "segueTest") {
               var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as secondViewController;

               svc.toPass = textField.text

           }
        }
```

in `secondViewController` you can define one variable like `String`

```
    var toPass:String!
```

In the `secondViewController` under the `viewDidLoad` function add this code

```
    println(\(toPass))
```

Comment: By Override...... .text } } are destinationViewcontroller and secondViewcontroller the names of the view controllers? If I change the name into 1viewcontroller and 2viewcontroller do I need to change segue!.destinationViewController as secondViewController; (; isn't needed for Swift?) to segue!.1ViewController as 2ViewController. And I'm using a label instead of a text, so svc.toPass = textField.text needs to be changed in svc.toPass = score.text score (is a UILabel)

Answer (score 0):

> FirstViewController

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

...

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? GameOverViewController {
        vc.score = Int(textField?.text)
    }
}

...
```

> SecondViewController

```
var score: Int!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

... 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    label.text = String(score)
}
```

This method will call when button was pressed, and in this place you may set some properties for your second view controller

Comment: Thank you. But what do I need to write in the other ViewController?

Comment: In second ViewController you have property "value" ( `var value: Int`). And for example in viewDidLoad() you may write something like this `resultScore.text = String(value)`

Comment: @USER1234 there where you define your properties `class ViewController: UIViewController {var valuer: Int! ... }`

Comment: Thank you for your help, there's only one question: I'm not using a textfield but a label. How do I need to change vc.score = Int(textField?.text) to an label declaration? (I'm a starting Swift user)

Comment: Don't worry. Just 'vc.score = Int(yourLabel?.text)'. Actually segue's is not simple thing for beginners

Comment: Thanks! that worked. Hopefully this is the last problem: I get a error on that line with "cannot find an initializer for type 'int' that accepts an argument list of type '(string?)'"

Comment: What version Swift do you use ? I use 2.0 in Xcode 7.0 (b4). I've attached example of project, I think it will be more clarify [sample](http://www.filedropper.com/testdel)

Comment: I'm Using Xcode version 6.4 with first version of Swift (I think because I think Swift 2.0 is available for 7. I openend your project and it give the same error.

Comment: Hm ok, then you may use `textField?.text.toInt() `

Comment: I've found the mistake textField?.text.toInt()  should be textfield?.text!.toInt(). But now when I click the button the app pauzes and goes back to xcode to Thread 1 to label.text = String(score) in the second view controller. label.text = String(score) is green with the note: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_Instruction (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

Comment: It means, something wrong with passed parameter. Let's step by step. 1. Check that textfield?.text!.toInt() returns correct value (not nill). Check that connections between IBOtlets in both view controllers are correct. Check which value GameOverViewController is recieved.

Comment: textfield?.text!.toInt() value is zero, the button is currently in storyboard/code 20. Where can I find the gameoverviewcontroller value?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to achieve that is you can use `NSUserDefault` for that.

first of all in your `playScene` when you are increasing your score you can store your score this way:

```
Score.text = "\(++score)"
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(score, forKey: "userScore")
```

After that in your next view controller you can get score this way:

```
resultScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("userScore")
```

Remember that type of your `resultScore` should be `Int`.

Comment: I'm not using sprite kit.